# Stochastic integral with non-anticipating integrand

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be a Brownian motion. We want to define $$ \int_{0}^{t} B_{s} dB_{s} : = \lim_{n \to \infty } \sum_{k = 1}^{2^{n}t} B_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}[ B_{\frac{k}{2^{n}}} - B_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}]. $$

To do this we notice that $$ B_{t}^{2}  =\sum_{k = 1}^{2^{n}t} [ B_{\frac{k}{2^{n}}} - B_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}]^{2} = 2 \sum_{k = 1}^{2^{n}t} B_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}[ B_{\frac{k}{2^{n}}} - B_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}] + \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n}t} [ B_{\frac{k}{2^{n}}} - B_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}]^{2} . $$

Now let $$ S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n}t} [ B_{\frac{k}{2^{n}}} - B_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}]^{2}. $$

From the definition of the Brownian motion, for all $ n $,  $ \mathbb{E} [ S_{n} ] = t $ and $ \mathrm{Var}(S_{n}) = 0 $, hence $ S_{n} $ converges in probability to $ t $.

Thus the first limits exists and we get also (unsurprisingly if one knows Ito's formula) that $$ \int_{0}^{t} B_{s} dB_{s} = \frac{B^{2}_{t}}{2} - \frac{t}{2}. $$

Now let $e(t,B_{t'})$ for $t' \leq t$, which we will indicate from now on as $e_{t}$, be a function such that is path wise continuous in $t$ and such that is *non-anticipating*, i.e., is only depends on Brownian motion up to the time $t$. Notice that this implies that $e_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}$ is independent from $[ B_{\frac{k}{2^{n}}} - B_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}]$.

In the same fashion as before I want to define $$ \int_{0}^{t} e_{s} dB_{s} : = \lim_{n \to \infty } \sum_{k = 1}^{2^{n}t} e_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}[ B_{\frac{k}{2^{n}}} - B_{\frac{k-1}{2^{n}}}]. $$

My question is that I am trying to replicate the proof above in order to prove that the limit exists but everyone of my attempts have failed.

The problem for me is that in this case I do not have the *a posteriori* knowledge due to Ito's formula that I have used in the previous prove also because I know nothing about the smoothness of $e$.

Comment: The theory of stochastic integrals is covered eg. in Revuz-Yor chapter IV-section-2 and here https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/lecture-16-ito-integral/, where they give conditions for the above function $e_{s}$ (for very irregular $e_s$ one cannot define the above integral eg. see rough path theory "a course in rough paths" book).

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no answer, I turn comment into answer.

The theory of stochastic integrals is covered eg. in Revuz-Yor chapter IV-section-2 and [Lecture 16. Itō integral](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/lecture-16-ito-integral) , where they give conditions for the above function $e_s$
(for very irregular $e_s$ one cannot define the above integral eg. see rough path theory "a course in rough paths" book).